# JOLT Transformation to filter contact type based on Array type

Tags: json, jolt

How to check condition in JSON Array. Considering below code, I need to filter based on contact type.If contact type contains Phone then phone type should be displayed.

```
{
  "entities": [
    [
      {
        "contactType": [
          "phone","email"
        ],
        "type": "111",
        "data": "111"
      },
      {
        "contactType": [
          "email"
        ],
        "type": "222",
        "data": "222"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "contactType": [
          "skype","phone"
        ],
        "type": "333",
        "data": "333"
      },
      {
        "contactType": [
          "email"
        ],
        "type": "444",
        "data": "444"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Based on contact type, I need to output, for example, for contact type "phone" the following output needs to be displayed:

```
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "type": "111",
      "data": "111"
    },
    {
      "type": "333",
      "data": "333"
    }
  ]
}
```

Jolt spec

```
 {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "entities": {
        "*": {
          "*": "entities.[]"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "entities": {
        "*": {
          "contactType": {
            "*": {
              "phone": {
                "type": "entities[&1].type",
                "data": "entities[&1].data"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

First I have merged array of array in to single array which contains both phone and email type. 
From contact type email or phone, it should be filtered in to single array.

Answer (score 0):

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "entities": {
        // collect all contact type and add it in one Array
        "*": {
          "*": "entities.[]"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "entities": {
        "*": {
          "contactType": {
            // loop thru each contactType for the phone type
            "*": {
              "phone": {
                "@3": "entities[]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "entities": {
        // removing contactType or adding type and data only
        "*": {
          "type": "entities[&1].type",
          "data": "entities[&1].data"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```